# How do I fix my OnRButtonDown() to detect right click for my dialog? (using mfc)

Tags: c++, mfc

Right now my code isn't detecting a right click on it's dialog.
Am I missing anything? Also, is there anything important I should know about how 
detection works in mfc?

Inside my .h file contains this method as a public:

```
afx_msg void OnRButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
```

In my .cpp file I have these guys:

```
void CGadgetAddedDialog::OnRButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{

char debugStr[1000];
sprintf_s(debugStr, "pressed on: %d, %d", point.x, point.y);
OutputDebugStringA(debugStr);

// TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
CDialogEx::OnRButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CGadgetAddedDialog, CDialogEx)
        ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
        ON_WM_RBUTTONDOWN()
        ON_WM_CONTEXTMENU()
        ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Comment: Have you tried using Spy++ to see who is handling the message? It's probably getting eaten by OnContextMenu.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on a child control with the right mouse key, the child control receives the message.

If you want to handle the right mouse click for a context menu than just use a handler for WM_CONTEXTMENU. This guaranties that also the context menu key is handled correct.
Also this message is transferred from a child to the parent if the child doesn't handle it.

Comment: In other words: Mouse input always goes to the window immediately underneath the mouse pointer. If the window is disabled, mouse input goes to the parent of that window.